Creative with issue from facebook, suddenly errors
I am facing issue about creating facebook ad via api,
My code was working and I am using v17 of meta apis,
After that when I try to create the ad I get this error too
{
  "error": {
    "message": "Invalid parameter",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 100,
    "error_subcode": 2490446,
    "is_transient": false,
    "error_user_title": "Creative status is WITH_ISSUES",
    "error_user_msg": "Creating ad using ad creative with WITH_ISSUES status is not allowed. The ad creative is in WITH_ISSUES status with error code 2643026 and error message: ‎خطأ أثناء معالجة الإعلان: نواجه مشكلة في معالجة طلبك. لحل المشكلة، يرجى محاولة النشر مرة أخرى. إذا كنت لا تزال تواجه مشكلات، يرجى التواصل مع فريق الدعم. نعتذر عن أي إزعاج.‎ Please fix the ad creative, try use recreate ad creative or another ad creative to proceed.",
    "fbtrace_id": "AWGR_J-QxQNRI6skOhmUuV2"
  }
}

I need to troubleshooting how can I find what's wrong with the creatives that I create

We need to see your code if you want us to help with debugging said code...

Thanks @TylerH The problem was no from the code, everything i working now with the same code and the same data, it seems that was something wrong from the facebok.

I face no issue from my code and api calling, and it was an issue from the facebook, after while I did the same flow for creating facebook ads and everything was working fine.
